# Send list of variables one class to other class in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, list, valuetuple

Here iam want send one class object properties to other class.my basic program look like here

```
class A():
    def __init__(self,name,age):
           Self.name = name
           Self .age = age
            Return tuple(self.name,self.age)
Class B():
       def __init__(self,oldInfo,job):
            Self.oldInfo=oldInfo
            Self.job=job
            Name,age= oldInfo
            Print(Name,age,job)
#calling block
Obj1=A("Scott","28")
Obj2=B(Obj1,"devolper")
```

So some errors are occurring like

> over unpack
>
> should return None not tuple
>
> return should be 1 value not multiple

Comment: Thanks loocid iam post query from mobile that why happens

Comment: Can you please fix the capitalization of all your variables and keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so when I answer this question, I think I should give you some advice.

1、python keywords is lower case with first letter,  **def** is not **Def**.others is also.
you can look my code or use this code in the idle.

```
import keyword
>>> keyword.kwlist
['False', 'None', 'True', 'and', 'as', 'assert', 'break', 'class', 'continue', 'def', 
'del', 'elif', 'else', 'except', 'finally', 'for', 'from', 'global', 'if', 'import', 
'in', 'is', 'lambda', 'nonlocal', 'not', 'or', 'pass', 'raise', 'return', 'try', 
'while', 'with', 'yield']
```

2、another is you should use the four space in your code with indent.

3、when you want to get the properties ,you should define the method in your code .the **Obj1=A("Scott","28")**, Obj1 is only a object with the class A, you can use the object to get your properties with method .

My code:

```
class A():

    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self .age = age

    def gettuple(self):
        return tuple([self.name,self.age])
class B():

    def __init__(self,oldInfo,job):

        self.oldInfo = oldInfo
        self.job = job
        (Name,age) = oldInfo
        print(Name,age,job)


#calling block
devolper = 'goggo'
Obj1=A("Scott","28")
Obj2=B(Obj1.gettuple(),devolper)
```

last time ,I think your should learn more in python.org with more examples [enter link description here](https://www.python.org/)

Answer (score 1):

1. Tuple should be `tuple((self.name,self.age))` instead of `tuple(self.name,self.age)`, because `tuple()` receives only 1 argument instead of 2.(I am not sure about this on python3)
2. `__init__()` should return None instead of a tuple, as it will create an object, try to figure it out.
3. as a result, `oldInfo` is "one" object, and you tried to unpack it into 2, name and age, therefore you got an "over unpack" error.

Answer (score 1):

the `__init__()` method must always return None. You can't make it return anything else. You can stick your tuple in a instance variable instead and then get that either using a getter method on your instance or (less pythonically) directly. You're also using `tuple()` incorrectly. `tuple()` takes a single argument as a tuple or a list, not two separate arguments. Calling `tuple()` isn't really necessarily either as you can create a new tuple simply by doing `foo = ('something', 'something else')`

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.tuple = (self.name, self.age)

class B():
    def __init__(self, oldInfo, job):
        self.oldInfo = oldInfo
        self.job = job
        name, age = oldInfo.tuple
        print(name, age, job)

obj1 = A("Scott", "28")
obj2 = B(obj1, "developer")
```

Also note that your tuple isn't really necessary as you have already assigned name and age as attributes in your A class. You can just call them from B since B already has a reference to the whole object:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

class B():
    def __init__(self, oldInfo, job):
        self.oldInfo = oldInfo
        self.job = job
        print(oldInfo.name, oldInfo.age, job)

obj1 = A("Scott", "28")
obj2 = B(obj1, "developer")
```